# When would you select with d3, as opposed to regular Javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say that I'm making a visualisation using the d3.js library, and suppose I have four sliders on a page. I want these sliders to set the attributes of a rectangle, and they look something like:

```
<input type = "range" value = "5" id = "xvalue">
<input type = "range" value = "5" id = "yvalue">
<input type = "range" value = "5" id = "width">
<input type = "range" value = "5" id = "height">
```

I can select these elements either with

```
d3.selectAll("input")
```

or with

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Looking at other d3 visualisations, I sometimes see people changing between the two.

When should you use each method?

Comment: When you want to use D3 functions, i.e, .attr() and so on, use d3.selectAll() otherwise it wont work with the javascript and when you want to use javascript such as .addClass() and so on use the javascript way. Kind of trivial to be honest ...

Comment: In addition to what @thatOneGuy said consider that under the covers D3 is using `document.querySelector` https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/select.js

Comment: Why is the use of document.querySelector in d3 significant?